# What is the difference between LMVT integral and differential form?

Tags: calculus

Differential : $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
Integral : $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = f(c)(b - a)$$

I am confused what to apply when, I will appreciate any hints also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral form is just a particular case of the first form.

If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is regular enough, say continuous, the function $g : ]a,b[ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by

$$
g(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x} f(t) dt
$$

(where $x_0$ is a fixed point of $I$) is well defined, continuous on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on $]a,b[$ with derivative $f$
so the first form of the theorem applied to $g$ gives $c \in ]a,b[$ such that

$$
g'(c) = \frac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a}
$$

i.e.
$$
f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(t) dt.
$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem for more information.

Comment: Thank you I understood thanks again